# Language dectection from tika-python does not work

Tags: python-3.x, apache-tika

I have an issue with the use of Tika for language detection (in python). I first remarked that when I **parse PDF files** with `parser.from_file(file)`, the **language was not included** in the "metadata part" in most cases.

Thus, I tried to explicitly **detect the language** and I **got** in most cases **"th"** as result, while my documents are in **french**. Then, I copied the PDF file content in a **simple text file** and the result was strangely **right**.
This is the code I used:

```
from tika import language 
print(language.from_file(file))
```

Let me notice that I just installed tika with the command `pip install tika` whithout any additional configuration. Is anything wrong in the process I used?

Answer (score 0):

from the documentation:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TIKA/TikaServer

"HTTP PUTs or POSTs a UTF-8 text file to the LanguageIdentifier to identify its language.

NOTE: This endpoint does not parse files.  It runs detection on a UTF-8 string."

you should first parse the pdf and extract the text, then run the language identifier:

```
pdf = parser.from_file(file_path, localhost_tika)
text = pdf["content"]
detected_lang = language.from_buffer(text)
```